# How to get a barcode with file format ppm for RWH's ch12?

Tags: haskell, ppm

I am studying [RWH's Ch12 Barcode Recognition](http://book.realworldhaskell.org/read/barcode-recognition.html). For understanding the contents more deeply, I want to generate a barcode with the file format **ppm** from scratch, but it is difficult for me to get a file `*.ppm`. Generally, the free online Barcode Generator such as [here](http://www.morovia.com/free-online-barcode-generator/) or Zint Barcode Studio 2.4, it only can generate file format `*.png` or `*.jpg`, so that I must convert `*.png` into `*.ppm` by [online converter](http://www.free-online-convert.com/PNG-to-PPM) or Gimp , but the produced `*.ppm` can not be processed  by `Barcode Recongnition`.

For this problem, I want to directly produce a file `*.ppm` using Java library [ZXing](https://github.com/zxing/zxing), but I have a same question that it seemly can not produce `*.ppm` directly.

what should I do? I hope you tell what (at best free) software or library can generate directly `*.ppm`?

Comment: PPM is a very simple file format,  you should just read the specs and figure out why your parser fails

Comment: yes format is very simple, search for "man pbm" or hit the netpbm website and read the docs there.

Comment: @NiklasB., Jasen, Thank you! You are right, PPM is very simple, but the contents in *.PPM may be not simple such as Barcode image, so I am afraid I can not handle it and submit such a question!

Comment: Couldn't you just use a paint program, perhaps in combination with e.g. `pngtopnm`?

Comment: @SamB, Thank you! Can you explain more?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[Netpbm](http://netpbm.sourceforge.net/)  contains tools to convert popular formats to pbm.

```
pngtopnm < file.png | ppmtopgm | pgmtopbm > file.ppm
```

pngtopnm may convert directly to pgm or ppm it depends on the the colour-space of the input file.

you may need `pnmtoplainpnm` on the end of the pipeline if your program is expecting plain ascii pbm

```
pngtopnm < file.png | ppmtopgm | pgmtopbm | pnmtoplainpnm > file.ppm
```

use `jpeg2pnm` instead of `pngtopnm` for jpg images.

Other free image editing tools such as the gimp, imagemagick, and fly may also support saving images as pbm.

Comment: ~Jasen, yes gimp can export *.jpg or *.png into *.ppm, but the produced *.ppm can not be correctly recognized by `RWH's PNM`, but `RWH's PNM` can handle the file getting from `pngtopnm < file.png > file.ppm`